# Update List item from DataGrid event CellEditEnding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, arraylist

I've loaded datagrid from a LIST. On every click event to a button it loads data to the LIST and eventually update the DataGrid by resetting the source.

Next thing I would like to do is to edit the values in Cell of that DataGrid and add it back to the List.

I've used struct to add data to List Items and DataGrid.
This is the struct:

```
public struct MyData {
public string item{get;set;}
public int number{get;set;}
}
```

Here is a code for CellEditEnding event.

```
int index = DataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
// I KNOW PROBLEM IS HERE as it selects the previous value not the changed value.
MyData foo = (MyData)DataGrid1.SelectedItem;
DataGrid1[index] = new MyData{item=foo.item.ToString(), number = 5}
```

Help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is still not clear to me but use 
`DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` in the CellEditEnding Event to gt the required values........ [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcelleditendingeventargs.aspx) link for Properties that might help you.